# Mathematical Jargon when choosing for determinacy

Tags: terminology, phrase-usage, science, scientific-language

What is the usual expression a mathematician uses when he has to make a choice in order limit an over-determined structure, in order to continue his argument?

For instance, when a structure is over-determined, a law may be true up to a sign. Deriving the law may require the mathematician/physicist to choose either sign and follow the formalism. This choice may become convention, eg. Hook's law for linear elasticity.

This is trivial and embarrassing, but I cannot remember nor can I find the answer on google. It has to be something along the lines of, "For the sake of determinacy, choose x from" or "For the sake of certainty, let x be." None of these sound quite natural though. Please help.

Comment: I've encountered _wlog_ ("without loss of generality") used in this way.

Comment: For Hooke's Law, F = kx describes the relationship where a simple helical spring that has one end attached to some fixed object, while the free end is being pulled by a force whose magnitude is F, and the extension caused is x.  But 'Hooke's law for a spring is often stated **under the convention that** F is the _restoring_ force exerted by the spring on whatever is pulling its free end. In that case, the equation becomes F = -kx' [[Wikipedia; modified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law)].

Comment: Fine, thanks, exactly. The question is really not about Hooks law, I only used it to illustrate the issue. I am asking what the usual textbook scientific jargon is when making choices while proving such laws.

Comment: WLOG is similar to what I mean but not exacly. While WLOG is only used only for simplicity, what is mean is a necessary (conventional) choice.

Comment: 'For the sake of argument, and without loss of generality, take ....'

Comment: You may get better answers on [math.se]. Your example is not particularly clear but your wording sounds like WOLG. But since you say it is 'not exactly' right, how about "By symmetry, the same argument follows for {the other choice}". Is that the kind of situation you're thinking of?

Comment: You must be right. I should think that I am lost in translation and that I have forgotten how the jargon goes. In fact, "WLOG" is suitable enough. I will consult a friend and close the question if he has no better idea. Thanks for the suggestions, everybody.

Comment: If you need to get from overdetermined to determined, you **relax a constraint**. If you need to go from underdetermined to determined, you **impose a constraint.**

Comment: You must mean a dynamical system. Note that I used the word "structure" instead. Thanks

Comment: In your example, if either sign would be OK and the difference doesn't really matter, I'd say "for the sake of definiteness" or just "for definiteness". (Being a set-theorist, I would not use "determinacy", which has a technical meaning in set theory.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"For the sake of argument, and without loss of generality" is quite good.

Thanks for all the comments and to Edwin Ashworth in particular.

**EDIT** Thanks, Andreas, it is "definiteness."